# Diagram of model not being updated when model updated from DB after table removal

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, edmx

I noticed that when I create a table in the DB and update the model, a new object corresponding to said table appears automagically in my diagram. However, when I remove a table and perform the same operation, the diagram stays unchanged.

[image]

I'm curious if there's a way to automate the process so the updated diagram is displayed. Is it intended behavior, by the way? What'd that be good for?

Comment: What options are you selecting in the Update Wizard: particularly on the Delete tab?

Comment: Nothing is selectable there. When I **add** a table, its name becomes selectable on the add-tab but when I **drop** one, nothing selectable appears on the delete-tab. Perhaps that's why the dropee isn't updated into the diagram... But why isn't it? And what to do about it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes this problem comes we have to do manually